# Pointer to a array of chars for string in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I was asked this on an interview for an entry level position and was interested as to why you need two pointers.  It was a phone interview and he had me write down

char **a[5]

and asked me what this was?

He told me that it was a pointer to an array of 5 characters in order to produce a string of 5 character.  I am just trying to understand why its char **a[5] and not char *a[5].

Comment: This is an array of five pointers-to-pointer-to-char. There are no direct chars here.If he said this is a pointer to an array of five chars either you wrote it wrong, he said it wrong, or both. The proper decl for his description is `char (*a)[5];` Side Note: Your `char *a[5];` is an array of five pointers-to-char, so that doesn't match his description either.

Comment: Thats just the way I wrote it down on for the questions.  Sorry that it was wrong, I didnt copy down what he said word for word but the important part would be that they use it to represent a string. What would be the advantage of having pointer to pointer to chars.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the right-left reading rule to that... a is an array of five pointers to a pointer to char.